# Battery Level on Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

Is it possible to get the battery level on an android app using phonegap?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Actually it is possible to get the battery level on PhoneGap. If you want you can register event listeners for the following events:

- "batterystatus" fired whenever the battery level changes by 1% or is
  plugged in or unplugged.
- "batterylow" fired when you reach the low battery threshold i.e. 20%
- "batterycritical" fired when you reach the critical battery threshold i.e. 5%

For some reason this hasn't shown up on the docs site. I will have to get that fixed.

Comment: this doesn't work...
document.addEventListener("batterystatus", batteryCheck, false);
 - i'm using android 2.1 (if that matters)

Comment: Using Android 2.1 doesn't matter. What version of PhoneGap are you using and do you have this line in your plugins.xml? &lt;plugin name="Battery" value="com.phonegap.BatteryListener"/&gt;

Comment: I'd have to see the logs from your app to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

To get battery level and plugged in status use below code:-

```
     //Battery Info
     document.addEventListener('batterystatus', batteryInfo, false);
     var level="Level: 50%";
     var isPlugged="Plugged: Yes";
     function batteryInfo(info){
        level="Level: "+info.level+"%";
        if(info.isPlugged){
            isPlugged="Plugged: Yes";
        }else{
            isPlugged="Plugged: No";
        }

        console.log("Level: " + info.level + " isPlugged: " + info.isPlugged);
     }
```

To show info, use level and isPlugged variable.